# Setting a cookie in javascript for a few pages

Tags: javascript

I have got two pages. example.com/php.com and example.com.

I use this function to set a page:

```
function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays)
{
                var exdate=new Date();
                exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
                var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
                document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value +" path=/";
  }
```

However, what I am trying to do , is to delete all the cookies before setting it...so I use this:...

```
function deleteAllCookies() {
var cookies = document.cookie.split(";");

for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
    var cookie = cookies[i];
    var eqPos = cookie.indexOf("=");
    var name = eqPos > -1 ? cookie.substr(0, eqPos) : cookie;
    document.cookie = name + "=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT";
}
}
```

Then whenever I am on a certain page... I execute both of those functions , one after the other.

```
 eraseCookie('user_details');
         setCookie('user_details',document.referrer,365);
```

The problem is htat the cookie is never set..and I wonder why..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Simple and elegant, always gets the job done.

Comment: i don't know but surely you don't need a library and a plugin just to set a cookie...

Comment: Depends, that library makes setting and erasing cookies a breeze. And it's just 43 lines of code...